# How to debug vega-lite specification? No data points seen plotted

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following vega-lite specification ([open vega-editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgtghgTg1iBcIAuBLAxnANCApgOzQHsATFPAcwVAE8qQAzFHAG2IRGihQDcJmBaVGBwhsSagAcRiJDjATCUPiAC+2AB51GLNohxII-XlwgERYydJABHAK6nUB1NxEq1IYhAMIA2qE48fIIowuwATAAMYQCM-BEA7PwAzNEABAnwGREALKK4BkbQKKZo0skRav5QXLwCQlaRMXGJKenxme05efqGxsVmCPwArNGVHNWBdSENUbEJyWkZKZkAbN0FfSVlSUPxYwG1waGIjXMti+3LEWvYPYUmA-DJAJxD+xOH9eGzzQtt8EkwvAhkN1r0iltBmFsgAOd41IJfE4-eatJZAkFg+79UpQmEreGTI4zJqoi7wbIRYGg24bCGPfjRbKEz7Tb6k87-SnUrGbR5JZmYKoIqbHECnX5o9rczG08EPXGZFmItnIjl-DIymn5eU4srRMIqAC6KiAA))
It seems very straightforward, but I don't see any data point being plotted.
There is no error, but a bunch of warnings, which I cannot make out to fix the problem.

I'd like to learn how to debug to vega-lite specifications. Or get help to correct some stupid mistakes of mine.

EDIT: (to keep the completeness of the lessons learned, here is the specification snippet, and the warnings:)

```
{
  "mark": "tick",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "arrival-time", "type": "temporal"},
    "x": {"field": "eta-variance", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "data": [
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:07:04", "eta-variance": -30},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:07:04", "eta-variance": -51},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:31:06", "eta-variance": -357},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:31:06", "eta-variance": -395},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:32:55", "eta-variance": -248},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:32:55", "eta-variance": -286},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:40:55", "eta-variance": -14},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:40:55", "eta-variance": 34},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:40:55", "eta-variance": 0},
    {"arrival-time": "2021-07-31 07:40:55", "eta-variance": -12}
  ]
}

[Warning] Validation: /data must be object of #/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must be object of #/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must be object of #/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must match a schema in anyOf of #/anyOf
[Warning] Validation: /data must be object of #/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must be object of #/definitions/SphereGenerator/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must be object of #/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must match a schema in anyOf of #/anyOf
[Warning] Validation: /data must match a schema in anyOf of #/anyOf
[Warning] Validation: /data must be null of #/properties/data/anyOf/1/type
[Warning] Validation: /data must match a schema in anyOf of #/properties/data/anyOf
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'facet' of #/required
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'layer' of #/required
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'repeat' of #/anyOf/0/required
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'repeat' of #/anyOf/1/required
[Warning] Validation: must match a schema in anyOf of #/anyOf
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'concat' of #/required
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'vconcat' of #/required
[Warning] Validation: must have required property 'hconcat' of #/required
[Warning] Validation: must match a schema in anyOf of #/anyOf
[Warning] Infinite extent for field "eta-variance": [Infinity, -Infinity]
[Warning] Infinite extent for field "arrival-time": [Infinity, -Infinity]
[Warning] Infinite extent for field "eta-variance": [Infinity, -Infinity]
[Warning] Infinite extent for field "arrival-time": [Infinity, -Infinity]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mikhail Akimov](https://vega-js.slack.com/team/U02EB1PRSS2) spotted my mistake that the specification of data was wrong.
The proper specification should be

```
{"data": {"values": [...]}
...}
```

The mistake is missing "values": and the associated structure.

The moral of the story is that vega-lite warnings are actually could be errors, and when it does not work, the warnings should be addressed as errors.